# How do I use the cmd to run a python program written in Spider

Tags: python

So I have gone into the cmd and found where my file I want to run is located. It is called **3.py** and my teacher had told us just to write "python 3.py" to run it. I did this and it doesn't say that there is anything wrong, it just does nothing. Almost like there is nothing to be read in the file **3.py**. But I open it just to make sure I'm not just trying to run an empty file. My file has something simple in it like *print("Hello there, this program is working")* so I know it isn't not running because of an error in the code.
I am using spider from anaconda to write my code into.

Comment: Where are you typing `python 3.py`? Please be specific, and maybe include a screenshot

Comment: where is `3.py` located?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to do it now. You have to use Anaconda prompt rather than cmd.